# How do I validate (or escape) the name field of a user so it won't break my email sending software?

Tags: perl, security, email, web

When sending a message I can have something like this to set the To field: (in Perl)

```
To: "$name" <$email>
```

In Perl I can validate the $email part with Email::Valid but how do I make sure the $name part accepts Unicode characters but cannot be tricked into sending to multiple addresses or doing some other nasty thing? e.g. This

```
$email = 'bar@me.com';
$name = 'Foo" <foo@other.com>, "Bar';
```

seem to create a To field like this:

```
To: "Foo" <foo@other.com>, "Bar" <bar@me.com>
```

sending e-mails to two addresses.

Comment: This is why I don't much care for send-email interfaces that parse the headers to determine the recipient list; the programmer should always need to supply a list of recipients in addition to the message headers and body, as it neatly eliminates problems like this, as well as reducing the complexity of such libraries.  (Consider the Bcc case, where the library must parse and then remove such a header.)

Answer (score 8):

```
use Email::Address qw();
use Encode qw(encode);

s{\R}{}g for $email, $name; # newlines be-gone
my $to = Email::Address->new($name => $email)->format;
print encode 'MIME-Header', $to;
```

Comment: Ensure that no characters can be passed that are seen by the SMTP server as carriage returns / newlines, otherwise it may be possible for a malicious user to send arbitrary messages.

Answer (score 2):

There may not be a simple solution to this. I'd recommend a conservative solution by hand.

```
/\p{L}/
```

matches any unicode letter in any language. Feel free to add dots or dashes, dependent on the cultural background of your software.